# Display CategoryName in JQGrid with Product Name and Price

Tags: c#, list, jqgrid

I have Product Model as below

```
public class Product
{
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
public int CategoryId {get;set;}
public float Price { get; set; }
public Category category { get; set; }
}
```

I have read Category ID and Category name in below method and now want to display Product Name, Category name and Price in JQGrid but it displays only Product Name and Price but not CayegoryName.

```
public JsonResult ShowProducts(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;

            BusinessLayer BusLayer = new BusinessLayer();

            List<Product> ProdList = new List<Product>();
            ProdList = BusLayer.ReadProducts();

            foreach (var Prd in ProdList)
            {
                Prd.category = BusLayer.GetCategoryById(Prd.CategoryId);                
            }

            int recordCount = ProdList.Count;
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)recordCount / (float)rows);

           var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                records = recordCount,
                rows = ProdList                
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Scrips to display is as below,

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Admin/ShowProducts",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Product Name', 'Category Name', 'Price', 'CatId'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'CategoryName', index: 'CategoryName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Price', index: 'Price', editable: true },
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'CATId', index: 'CatId', editable: true },
            ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 5,
......
......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

In Product, ProductName is of type string where as Category property is not of type string. So converting Category to string type to hold category name should be done.

Along with that, In jqGrid properties colModel name to represent direct mapping to the properties. So for category, name should be category than category name. The update is as made below,

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Admin/ShowProducts",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Product Name', 'Category Name', 'Price', 'CatId'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Category', index: 'Category', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Price', index: 'Price', editable: true },
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'CATId', index: 'CatId', editable: true },
            ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 5,
```